# Como guardar varios checkbox en un solo campo de la tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

tengo varios checkbox y necesito guardar 3 de los que el usuario seleccione en un solo campo de la tabla y condicionar al usuario de que solo puede seleccionar 3.
Este es mi codigo Html y necesito condicionarlo con php, el campo de la tabla en mysql se llama TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre

```
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label no-padding-right" for="NumeroHijos">Cuáles de los siguientes son temas de interés y que realizas dentro de tu tiempo libre (Máximo 3)</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" id="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" value="Deportes">Deportes

                    <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" id="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" value="Cocina">Cocina

                    <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" id="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" value="Lectura">Lectura

                    <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" id="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" value="Pintura">Pintura

                    <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" id="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" value="Teatro">Teatro

                    <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" id="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" value="Ejercicio y alimentación fitness">Ejercicio y alimentación fitness

                    <input type="checkbox" name="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" id="TemasDeInteresTiempoLibre" value="Enseñanza">Otro:

                </div>
```

Comment: No puedes condicionar esto con PHP, deberías usar Javascript, escuchando cuando los checkbox sean seleccionados y llevando un contador, cuando el mismo llegue a 3 deshabilitas los no chequeados y si se deschequea uno, los vuelves a habilitar (así evitas que se seleccionen más de tres)... es algo relativamente fácil, pero olvídate de hacer esto desde PHP, este tipo de cosas debes realizarlas en el cliente, no en el servidor.

Comment: y como guardo los 3 checkbox en un solo campo de la tabla?

Comment: Son dos preguntas en una: por un lado el control de un máximo de tres elementos seleccionados y por otro el asunto de guardarlos en una tabla... Ni siquiera queda claro a qué tabla te refieres: ¿una tabla en la base de datos?, ¿una tabla HTML?. Sea como sea, debes siempre indicar lo que has intentado y qué problemas concretos tienes, eso también falta en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En las tablas mysql para este tipo de situacion se usa la relacion de tablas, en este caso de uno a muchos osea un elemento en la tabla y muchos elementos disponibles para ella, esta es la forma mas elegante con un id en la tabla relacion A y con un IDtablaA en la tabla de relacion B.

Otra solucion muchisimo menos elegante en este caso seria que desde PHP sacar el value de los check que se enviaron desde el navegador y los coloques separados por un "-", guion medio, usando la funcion implode()

```
$array = array('valuecheck1', 'valuecheck2', 'valuecheck3');
$separado_por_guiones = implode("-", $array);
```

esto cuando lo guardes en la DB creara algo como esto

valuecheck1-valuecheck2-valuecheck3

Comment: y como se si esta seleccionado y que se guarde en ese array?

Comment: cuando un checkbox se selecciona en el navegador, el formulario envía el value de lo contrario no se envia el value del checkbox, para eso cada uno de tus ckec deberia tener un value diferente, un name diferente y un id diferente, en tu caso el codigo tiene problemas por esa parte, en lugar de id, pusiera class="" y en los name todos serian con la extencion del valor al que hacen referencia por ejemplo: TemasDeInteresTiempoLibreDeportes